# change email associated with php mail function

Tags: php, email

I'm using the php mail() function and I'd like to change where the mail is comming form, ie: from the default site email to a specific email address.  I'm using Dreamhost as my hosting provider.

I've tried this:

```
    <?php
$name = $_GET['name'];
$email = $_GET['email'];
$comment = $_GET['comment'];
$todayis = date("l, F j, Y, g:i a") ;
$subject = "A message sent on ".$todayis." from ".$name." via the playatics website";
$message = " Message: $comment \r \n From: $name  \r \n Reply to: $email";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'From: Domain Name contact@domain.com' . "\r\n";   

mail("somemail@domain.com", $subject, $message);

?>
```

Comment: This should mostly work except you have the `From` header in an incorrect format. You should have `Domain Name <contact@domain.com>`.

Answer (score 4):

You are a whisker away from the answer here. You are setting a variable `$headers`, but you are not using it when calling the `mail()` function.

```
<?php
$name = $_GET['name'];
$email = $_GET['email'];
$comment = $_GET['comment'];
$todayis = date("l, F j, Y, g:i a") ;
$subject = "A message sent on ".$todayis." from ".$name." via the playatics website";
$message = " Message: $comment \r \n From: $name  \r \n Reply to: $email";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'From: Domain Name contact@domain.com' . "\r\n";   

mail("somemail@domain.com", $subject, $message, $headers);

?>
```

That should do it.

Comment: holy canoli! haha! yes I was whiskers away, that did it!  Thanks

Comment: Any chance you can mark this answer as correct then? (I think you will see a checkmark to the left of my response.) Just means that this question will be marked as closed (and I get a little bit of reputation for the answer).

Answer (score 0):

You need to use your headers I think (see http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php)

Answer (score 0):

Not directly an answer to your question, but check out [PHPMailer](http://phpmailer.worxware.com/) if you plan on doing a fair bit of emailing in PHP. It makes things nice and easy :)